# I want to align images from different divs within in my Bootstrap 4 Accordion Card above each other

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, accordion, vertical-alignment

I have an arrow image in each heading of my Bootstrap 4 Accordion Card. My goal is to have them all line up above each other on the right edge(but still within) the card's border. Everything i've tried so far either pushes the arrows out of the card or makes them go below the rest of the header.

I've tried justify-content, align-content, and align-items but none of them have worked yet. Any tips on how to achieve this would be appreciated. Below is how it looks currently.
[image]

```
<div class="card">
      <h3> FAQ </h3>
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne"> 
         How many team members can I invite? <img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" class="arrow"> 
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
         You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on 
  team members for the Premium plan.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
#accordion{
      
      width:30%;
      float: right;
      position:relative;
      top: 300px;
      right: 900px;
      align-content: center;
      font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
      
      
  }

  .card-header{
      
      background-color: white;
      clear: both;
    
      
  }
  
  .arrow{
      
      
  }
  
  button{
      position:relative;
      left:-32px;
  
  }
```

Comment: What you're looking for is that make your h5 element into a flex element and utilize `justify-content: space-between`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by making your `<h5>` element into a flex row and utilize the `justify-content` property with `space-between`.

**Example**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="card">
    <h3> FAQ </h3>
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne"> 
         How many team members can I invite?
        </button>
        v
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on 
        team members for the Premium plan.
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#accordion {      
    width:30%;
    float: right;
    position:relative;
    top: 300px;
    right: 900px;
    align-content: center;
    font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
}

.card-header {
    background-color: white;
    clear: both;
}

.card-header h5 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
  
button{
    position:relative;
    left:-32px;
}
```

I'm using `V` instead of your image to visualize the effect, but the result is the same.

**Snippet:**

```css
#accordion {      
    width:30%;
    float: right;
    position:relative;
    top: 300px;
    right: 900px;
    align-content: center;
    font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
}

.card-header {
    background-color: white;
    clear: both;
}

.card-header h5 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
  
button{
    position:relative;
    left:-32px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card">
    <h3> FAQ </h3>
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne"> 
         How many team members can I invite?
        </button>
        v
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on 
        team members for the Premium plan.
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Codepen example [here](https://codepen.io/mbacode/pen/oNzGqMW).

I would also suggest checking out [this very simple guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on Flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

I generate a sample to get same behaviour with Bootstrap 4 and I move your arrow `<img>` to inner of the `<h5>` tag. After that `float:right` attribute pulls the element to the right.

```css
.xl {
  width:100%; 
  border: solid 1px #333;
}

#accordion{
  margin-left:30px;
  width:60%;          
}
  
.arrow{
  width:36px;
  height: auto;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='xl'>
<h3>Some Header</h3>
<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">Collapsible Group Item #1 
        </button>
        <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f1/Down_Arrow_Icon.png' class='arrow'>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2 
        </button>
        <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f1/Down_Arrow_Icon.png' class='arrow'>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3 
        </button>
        <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f1/Down_Arrow_Icon.png' class='arrow'>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```